# Crystal Reports - Change DataSource name

Tags: crystal-reports

We are using a 3rd party HR Tool (NuView) and are creating custom reports in Crystal. The source data is a csv file. In order for NuView to process the Crystal Report it REQUIRES that the:

1. csv file name
2. datasource name in Crystal
3. the report name

be the same.

For example, if it was a report on ADDRESSES - Address.csv,  Address#csv.fieldname, Address.rpt

Here's our dilemma - we are creating some complex reports and want to REUSE them. So, we want to take an existing CR report and copy it and then * CHANGE THE DATASOURCE * name - and we can not figure out how to to this?!?

We can change the source file (e.g., Address.csv) and the report name - but for some reason can not figure out how (or if it is possible) to change the Address#csv (which I'm calling the datasource name.

Just trying to save our dev staff some time from having to re-create very similar reports from scratch. We are using MS ACCESS/Jet to read the csv file (per NuView)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Lee! We were in Field Explorer - going to Database > Expert did the trick :-) Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `Database Expert` you can simply right click on it in the right hand pane `selected tables` and choose rename. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you Lee! We were in Field Explorer - going to Database > Expert did the trick :-) Thanks again